# Zend Framework - Load a module in application/Bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework

```
application
|-Payment
| | +--Item
| |   +---Footer.php
| +--Manager.php
|-Boostrap.php
```

In application/Boostrap.php I want to init Payment module like this:

```
protected function _initPaymentManager()
{
    $manager = Payment_Manager::getInstance();  
    $manager->registerHandler(new Payment_Item_Footer());   
}
```

But the framework have not loaded Payment module yet. How can I call classes in Payment module in application/Bootstrap.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that the modules resource is loaded first, add:

```
$this->bootstrap('modules');
```

to the start of your `_initPaymentManager` method.

You'll also need a `Bootstrap.php` in the `application/Payment/` folder.